# How do you write a karma/jasmine integration test that passes values to the next test in sequence?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, integration-testing, frontend, karma-jasmine

I'm building a front-end web app that connects through API to the back-end.

I've got a case where I need to run a set of integration tests in the correct sequence, ie. register has to be run before login (so that an account is created that can be used for the login). But not sure how to do this with karma/jasmine, because if I'm not mistaken, all tests are run simultaneously in-parallel...?

As well, the register script generates a random username each time the test is run, so I need to be able to pass this variable to the login script (each is in a separate file).

Any idea how I should set this up?

Note: I have unit tests that use mock endpoint calls and mock data, those work fine. But what I'm referring to in this case are the integration tests that connect to a test back-end to make sure the integration points are working correctly.

Comment: this is more suited for Protractor (http://angular.github.io/protractor/) than Karma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some support for running tests in order in Jasmine 2, [see documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support)

As you said in your comment, you should have a main test file and then require() your other files:

**main.js**

```
var param = 'Stage 1';

describe('Test start', function() {
    require('./firsttest')(param, function(stage3param) {
        console.log(stage3param);
        require('./nextfile')(stage3param, function(stageXparam) {
            // Callback hell
        });
    });
});
```

**firsttest.js**

```
module.exports = function(param, callback) {

describe("first test", function() {

    it("should run this first", function(done) {
        console.log(param);
        param = 'Stage 2';
        done();
    })

    it("should run this second and then continue with callback", function() {
        console.log(param);
        param = 'Stage 3';
        callback(param);
    });
});
}
```

This outputs:

LOG: 'Stage 1'
LOG: 'Stage 2'
LOG: 'Stage 3'

Comment: Nice, thanks. I'll give this a shot and see how it goes. I'm wondering if there might be complications because it's an AngularJS/require.js application. I'll let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 3):

Karma & Jasmine is a very bad fit to this sort of testing plan. 
The tests are designed to be atomic and executed in no particular order.

- You could execute the depended test in one large *scenario*
- Or write a ([setup and teardown](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown)) for the tests.
- Or implement a back-end helper function(s) to push the required state to
  the server.

Overall, there is no one right solution to this problem => [End to End Angular Testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQipuiTcn3U#t=1024)

I would recommend you to update to [Protractor](http://angular.github.io/protractor/) from Karma/Jasmine, when running E2E tests, though it will not solve your current challenge.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I'm supposed to be building all of the above: unit tests, integrated/midway, and UI tests (for which I'll be using Protractor). Frankly, I feel this is overkill because the UI testing will take care of integrated tests too. But my life is now complicated with figuring out how I can do this integrated component. Not sure how setup/teardown would help, or maybe I don't understand how to set those up on a global level (passed between *_test.js files). I'm thinking that maybe I can use one *_test.js file, and have it use node's `require()` to get files in sequence.